# Android round corner and bitmap repeated background

Tags: android-layout

I'm trying to have the following background for a Layout in my Android Application :

[image]

So I need 2 rounder corner, and a repeated checkered background. and of course the height and weight are not fixed :)

I've tried to build a shape with this attributs, but I can't use a checkered background ...
And I can't use a 9 path because of the checkered background ...